# How do you override a transitive nuget dependency

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-6.0

I have a net6.0 project where one of the packages has a transitive dependency on another package that has a vulnerability.

I also explicity have added the latest version of the package with the vulnerability. Is there a way I can override the transitive dependency with the updated version?

Comment: "explicity have added the latest version of the package with the vulnerability" did you mean *without* the vulnerability?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you've already done it - you can only use one version of each package, which NuGet picks at restore time.

If you've got a direct reference to the newer version then that is the version that will get picked due to the [nearest wins rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins).